# How can I align the UI like in the photo

Tags: flutter, dart

Can anyone please let me know how I can align the highlighted part and the form like in the design? I tried using Stack, and Column but couldn't figure out the alignment. Assume that the highlighted part contains two circular Containers.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you've written and the current result you're getting.

Comment: Actually I have not written any code yet. I tried but it didn't work so I removed all the code.

Comment: Oh, you should place your Image and Form in a stacked widget. The image (preferably svg) should be in a positioned widget with the properties top and left set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the template that you are showing is using a Stack with two childrens.

One of them is the form with the image.
The other one, is the highlighted that I think it is using a CustomClipper (WaveClipper is just an example of a Clipper, you should play with it in order to get the design in your picture)

You can learn more about Clippers here [Flutter Clippers](https://medium.com/@mg55851/flutter-clippers-1fa3666f2bef)

```
Stack(
     children: [
       Center(
         child: 
           ClipPath(
              clipper: _WaveClipper(),
              child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color:Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
               ),
             ),
            ),
        Center(
          child: Container(),
           ),
          ],
)

class _WaveClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    var path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, 150);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 4, 90, size.width / 2, 105);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(3 / 4 * size.width, 110, size.width, 60);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```